# shell, compare argument to an array

Tags: shell, text-files

This is my code. It was working perfectly, before I restarted my computer.
I might have not saved before I reboot. I am not sure.

```
if  [[ "${varA[@]}" =~ $comment ]]
        then
           echo "This task is already in the Todo list"
        else
           x=$(cat $file | wc -l)
           x=$(($x+1))
           echo -e "$x\t$comment\t$dueD" >> $file
fi
```

I want to check if `$comment` is in array varA, and if it exists then 
`echo` it, else to add it.
Please help.

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to put variables like `$comment` and `$file` in double quotes.

Comment: No need for `$(cat $file | wc -l)`, use `wc -l "$file"`

Comment: it is always adding to the text file

Comment: Jahid, the problem is not in the else statement, the if is not working, as if it is not read

Comment: @jangler `"$file"` wants quotes but `$comment` probably doesn't *unless* its contents are potentially a pattern and don't want to be matched as such. The contents of `[[` aren't word-split.

Comment: Your problem is somewhere else--the syntax of the if statement is correct; however, note that if, for example, "doghouse" is an element of `varA` and `$comment` is "dog", then you'll get a match--which is probably not what you want.

Comment: @Jahid The `cat | wc` pattern is to avoid the filename in the `wc` output. `wc -l file` -> `## file` but `cat file | wc -l` -> `##`.

Comment: @jangler you are right about what you said, i just ran into this now

Comment: @EtanReisner I see, but using cat just for that seems very inefficient. `file` can be omitted easily with `x="${x/ file/}"` or other ways..

Comment: @jangler any ideas how to fix this issue if i want to "get books" and "get water", then it is showing that i have a match, due to the word "get"

Comment: @Jahid i am inefficient, this is my first time i use shell bash scripting, i am still not familiar with the language

Comment: Use `for` to loop through the array, and check each element for exact match to `$comment` using `==` instead of `=~`.

In a silly one-liner: `if [[ $(for e in "${varA[@]}"; do if [[ "$e" == "$comment" ]]; then found=1; break; fi; done; echo $found) ]]`

Comment: @jangler when i added your code, it only printed "This task already in the Todo list" i also tried fixing it and still did not work, moreover, now when i returned the original code, it no longer read the else condition

Comment: @Jahid Indeed. `wc -l <file` is clearly better but a slightly more "advanced" concept.